# Find the general solution to this linear ODE

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to this linear ODE
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)X
$$
Where$$X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \in\ R^3 $$

Do I begin by computing the eigenvalues and vectors for this matrix? I did and they seem to be complex so im struggling with where to go from here. Any help appreciated as always.

Comment: one of the eigenvalue is $-1$ and a an eigenvector is $(0,0,1)^T$

Comment: The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $-\frac 12\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}2i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the eigenvalues are $$-1, -\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt3}2 \, i, -\frac12 - \frac{\sqrt 3}2 \,i$$  and the corresponding eigenvectors are $$w = \pmatrix{0\\0\\1},u \pm iv, \text{ where }u = \pmatrix{2\\-1\\1, }, v = \pmatrix{0\\\sqrt 3\\-\sqrt 3 }   $$  you can verify that 
$$x = e^{-t}w, x = e^{-t/2}\pmatrix{\cos \sqrt 3t/2& -\sin \sqrt 3 t/2\\ \sin \sqrt 3t/2& \cos \sqrt 3 t/2}\pmatrix{u\\v}$$ is a fundamental set of solutions.

Comment: I just got round to working through this thanks for your help regardless, abel, it took me way to long.